# \\wsl.localhost is not accessible. Open folder error

Tags: networking, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to access wsl folder in File Explorer however I got this error

> \wsl.localhost is not accessible. You might not have permission to
> use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to
> find out if you have access permissions.
>
> The network address is invalid

WSL detail:
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2215

I also had turned on my network discovery

and here is my reg

PS C:\Users\xxx> reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider /s

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder
ProviderOrder    REG_SZ    cbdisk3,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,P9NPe

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
ProviderOrder    REG_SZ    RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,P9NPen

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\ProviderOrder
LanmanWorkstation    REG_DWORD    0x7d0
P9NP    REG_DWORD    0x1f4
RDPNP    REG_DWORD    0x3e8
webclient    REG_DWORD    0xbb8
cbdisk3    REG_DWORD    0x1f4
P9NPe    REG_DWORD    0xfa0
P9NPen    REG_DWORD    0xfa0

how can I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. You just need to add `P9NP` to

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder`

For example:

```
P9NP,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,<etc>,<etc>
```

Comment: I have the same problem though P9NP is in my registry keys...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to fix that some might find useful.

"\wsl.localhost" is unavailable to write to because of a security vulnerability.  Writing to it directly is not possible, however you can map it as a network drive.  After that it's fully accessible.

Drive Y network mount example:

[image: Drive Y Network Mount Example]